# JS Array.prototype.filter with Array extending class constructor call

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, filter

I have a Array extending class A which I want to filter. It seems like the constructor gets called another time with just `0` as parameter. Why is that?

Here is an example showing the problem:

```
class A extends Array {
   constructor(...a){
      console.log(a)
      super(...a);
   }
}

let a = new A("ok", "long");

let b = a.filter((e) => {
   return e.length === 4;
});

console.log(b);
```

Which logs:

```
[
    "ok",
    "long"
]
[
    0
]
[
    "long"
]
```

Where is the 0 comming from?

Comment: `.filter` is returning a new array, which needs to be an instance your class.

Comment: it comes from your construcfor when filter creates the returning array

Comment: but why would it give me a 0 and not just no paramenter

Comment: @zzrv because if you see the polyfill here, `filter` pre allocates the array to be returned: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` is returning a new (array) value. That value needs to be of the same "type" as the original array, i.e. it has to be an instance of your class.

`.filter` creates a new empty instance of your class:

> 1. Let *O* be ? [ToObject](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-toobject)(**this** value).
>   [...]
>   5. Let *A* be ? [ArraySpeciesCreate](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-arrayspeciescreate)(*O*, 0).
>   [...]

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.filter

> but why would it give me a 0 and not just no paramenter

Because the spec says that the new array is created by calling its constructor with (length) `0` as argument.